# What causes this error of incorrect number of dimensions when using describe()?

Tags: r, error-handling, datatable, label, describe

I have a dataset, where one column takes values 1-7. It also has some NA fields.
This data was imported through an spss file and thus has value labels.

I tried using this function to see the value labels:

```
describe(df$col)
```

But it returned this error:

```
Error in proxy[, ..., drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I am not sure what that means. I thought it might mean that there were too many varying answers, but it's literally just 1-7.

table(df$col) returns:

```
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
1707  214  103   74  297   54   70
```

I just want to see what those numbers represent. I worked with the data and I want to see if the labels stayed there despite making changes.

Comment: Where is the `describe()` function coming from? What packages are you using? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Try this: `library(psych) 
df <- col[complete.cases(df), ]
describe(df$col)`

Comment: Multiple errors with that one. Object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. Describe is part of other package I have activated. Unexpected symbol.

Comment: It didn't add the @ so I try again @TarJae